# error Instance of 'Response' en flutter

Tags: nodejs, flutter, dart

estoy intentando enviar un json a mi back para generar un excel, pero me sale este error he intentado de todo y no e dado con el chiste, mi servicio en dart es:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ExcelService {
 Future<http.Response> generateExcel(data) async {
try {
  http.Response response = await http
      .post(Uri.http('localhost:8080', '/jsontoexcel'), body: data);

  print(response);
  return response;
} catch (e) {
  return e;
}
}
}
```

y mi back esta en node y el post es:

```
app.post('/jsontoexcel', (req, res) =>{
console.log("asdadadadadasdadsa")
var jsondata = req.body.json
var exceloutput = Date.now() + "output.xlsx"

if(isJson(jsondata)){
    var xls = json2xls(JSON.parse(jsondata));
    fs.writeFileSync(exceloutput, xls, 'binary'); 
    res.download(exceloutput, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.unlinkSync(exceloutput)
            res.send("uneable to download the excel  file")
        }
        fs.unlinkSync(exceloutput)
    })
}else{
    res.send("JSON data is not valid")
}
})
```

la respuesta que me esta devolviendo el request cuando se imprime es error Instance of 'Response' y en el console.log del back no me aparece nada , por lo que creo que no le esta llegando. Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En como realizas tu petición me parece que hay un error muy importante y razón por la que puede que no llegue a tu **back-end**.

la dirección de tu **back-end** no puede ser `'localhost:8080'` ya que estas desde un dispositivo móvil, en caso de un emulador desconozco la situación, pero para evitar errores recomiendo que coloques la dirección **IP** de tu maquina ejemplo: `192.168.10.1:8080`

---

### Instance of 'Response'

Esto es por que solo imprimes `response`, si quieres obtener la respuesta al igual que el status de tu server puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Si el servidor devolvió una respuesta 200 OK,
    // Imprimir respuesta
    print(response.body);
}
```

puedes encontrar mas información al respecto en la [documentación](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)